# How to correctly compare "year" using strtotime in the included script

Tags: php, strtotime

My error validation isn't working.  I have tried so many different methods and it seems like maybe the year is not a valid comparison.  Please tell me if the example code looks good and the problem must exist somewhere else.

Here is my script:

```
if( isset( $arr_posts['group_event_start'] ) && date("Y",strtotime($arr_posts['group_event_start']) >= date("Y") ) ){
        
            UM()->form()->add_error('group_event_start', __(date('Y',strtotime($arr_posts['group_event_start'])). ' You must enter a valid start date/time.','um-groups') );        

        }
```

Here is a sample date:
**01/01/2021 12:00 AM**

The error message is outputting the following:
**2021 You must enter a valid start date/time.**

This shows that it is recognizing 2021 but not comparing it correctly with date("Y), doesn't it?  2021 is clearly greater than 2020.

I have even removed the first argument of the conditional just using the date comparison only.  It never validates correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing a colon i think `(date('Y',strtotime($arr_posts['group_event_start'])))`

Comment: It's not missing a parenthesis, they're just not grouped right. This is what you want: `date("Y",strtotime($arr_posts['group_event_start'])) >= date("Y") )`.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I wish syntax errors wouldn't escape me so much! lol!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see one date() inside the other date() following parenthesis order.

Maybe you are trying to compare **date("Y") >= date("Y")**, so you would need to change the parenthesis.